Django: Caching objects for search results
I'm stuck on what the approach should be for caching serialized objects as part of search queries. Right now, the serializers are performing extra queries and even with prefetch_related, a typical query is taking around 40 seconds to complete.
            trips = (
                Trip.objects.filter(filter_query)
                .prefetch_related(
                    "trip_values",
                    "trip_values__operator_trip_field",
                    "trip_values__operator_trip_field__trip_field",
                    "operator_service_day",
                    "trip_occurrences",
                    "trip_locations",
                    "assigned_vehicle_formation",
                )
                .all()
            
            query_time = time.time() - search_start
            print("Query time: ", query_time)
            serialization_start = time.time()
            serialized = TripListSerializer(trips, many=True)
            serialization_time = time.time() - serialization_start
            print("Serialization time: ", serialization_time)

            return Response(serialized.data)

So, if I wanted to cache each object instead, I would have to perform the same query as above, but I would then need to loop over each id and fetch it's cache and then combine the cache. So if i have 200+ search results, that's 200+ cache lookups.
Is that really the approach I'm suppose to go or is there a better alternative.
Additionally, with respect to time logging, I notice that the serialization time is actually very small, but the time for the Response to finish is the majority of the time for the request. Is there anything I can do to speed that up?

This is a very broad question, and I think the only answers possible are opinion based ones.  Here's mine: use a trigger to keep a "search" table up to date when values change, and then query against that.  Or use elastic search?  Or reduce what values you allow querying against to bring the time down?  Raw sql?

Right ... there are tradeoff to all approaches. I could replace model serializers with standard serializers - this seems to be the solution from here: https://hakibenita.com/django-rest-framework-slow. None of your solutions rely on cache so I guess my cache suggestion isn't great?

Caching can work great, but the hardest thing is knowing when to invalidate the cache.  I'd need to know a lot more about your data, what exactly you want to cache, how it used & updated - so I just didn't bring it up.  If you can cache out the prefetch-related that might help though?  I would start by watching which queries are executed, and then trying to make hand-optimized work-alike queries at least.  For something important it's not a big deal to do the extra work for a raw query, it's actually recommended.

What does your query take without the prefetch and serialization?  I'd start there, just see what that base query takes and start narrowing down the issue.

Raw queries for highly dynamic query parameters is going to be a challenge. Where does it say it's recommended?

@AlxValleo Yes, it is work to do, but there are libraries, and if you are creative you can extract where clauses from the orm and hand roll the select.  As with everything, there is a point at which the libraries don't do it well - knowing when to do it by hand is the advice with every ORM, google "when to use raw vs orm" for a variety of opinons.  Here is one short article on django's : https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/djangos-orm-vs-raw-sql-when-to-use-which
